# How do i make my css root rule work for my website

Tags: html, css

I created a card which i would like it to translate along the y-axis and throw a shadow upon hover. The translation along the y-axis is working well but the shadow doesn't get thrown when i hover over the card. I wrote the following css rule and i don't know if i got it right, because it clearly is NOT working on everything i applied it on:

```css
:root {
  --brand: #b33030;
  --body: #606060;
  --dark: #19282f;
  --border-radius: 4px;
  --shadow: 0px 4px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}


/* reset & helpers */

body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: var(--body);
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: var(--dark);
  font-family: "Domine", sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: var(--dark);
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}

a:hover {
  color: var(--brand);
}

a.custom-link {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

section {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.section-intro {
  margin-bottom: 33px;
  text-align: center;
}

.section-intro p {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.custom-card {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
}

.custom-card:hover {
  box-shadow: var(--shadow);
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}


/* Hero */

#hero {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url(../../../assets/images/hero_bg_img.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#hero h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
}

#hero h1,
#hero p {
  color: white;
}

#hero p {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 12px auto 24px auto;
}

#hero button {
  padding: 12px 28px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 40%;
}

#hero button:focus {
  box-shadow: 1px;
}


/* button */

.btn {
  padding: 12px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}

.btn-brand {
  background-color: var(--brand);
  color: white;
}

.btn-brand:hover {
  color: white;
}


/* Navbar */

.navbar.bg-white {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover .navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  color: var(--brand);
}


/* Features */

.features {
  padding: 44px 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.icon-box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: var(--brand);
  color: white;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  font-size: 34px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.features h5 {
  margin-top: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.features p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!-- NAV -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white sticky-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#login">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- END OF NAV-->
<!-- HERO -->
<section id="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1 class="display-3">Brighter Brain</h1>
        <p>
          Creating a pathway to make access to education easier, flexible and profound.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p>
        <button class="btn btn-brand" type="button" id="button">
              Get started.
            </button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- END OF HERO-->

<!-- FEATURES -->
<section id="features">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 section-intro">
        <h1>Our Features</h1>
        <p>
          We have a very significant number of features which will help make educational life easily.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="features custom-card">
          <div class="icon-box">
            <i class="ri-live-fill"></i>
          </div>
          <h5>Features Title</h5>
          <p>
            Integrated administrative design and monitoring of teaching manuals, digital class and examinations deployable anywhere and anytime.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="custom-link">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- END OF FEATURES -->
```

The root rule in the CSS is suppose to handle all color applications, hovers et al BUT it is not working. Am i doing this right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at the snippet I created from your code, it seems to be working; could you verify that the code is accurate, and reproduces the problem you describe?

Comment: I've just run @DavidThomas snippet and confirm that it seems to be working fine (the card goes up slightly on hover and the shadow appears). Perhaps try giving the shadow a color like red to make it more obvious just to reassure yourself that it is there.

Comment: @DavidThomas I can confirm that the code is accurate and it produces the problem i described. I ran the code on Chrome and Firefox and it is not working as it is on the snippet. I have even tried in on Microsoft Edge, it is still the same. I am creating this website as an angular project. A Haworth, I did change the color to red, it is still the same. To make matters worse, the red icon which appeared in the card on the snippet did not even appear when i ran the code.

Answer (score 0):

I just threw your code into a runnable snippet and the shadow on hover seems to be working for me.

I darkened it to 0.5 opacity so it's more obvious.

```css
:root {
  --brand: #b33030;
  --body: #606060;
  --dark: #19282f;
  --border-radius: 4px;
  --shadow: 0px 4px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
/* reset & helpers */
body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: var(--body);
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: var(--dark);
  font-family: "Domine", sans-serif;
}
a {
  color: var(--dark);
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}
a:hover {
  color: var(--brand);
}

a.custom-link {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
section {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.section-intro {
  margin-bottom: 33px;
  text-align: center;
}
.section-intro p {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}
.custom-card {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
}
.custom-card:hover {
  box-shadow: var(--shadow);
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}

/* Hero */
#hero {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)),
    url(../../../assets/images/hero_bg_img.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
#hero h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
}

#hero h1,
#hero p {
  color: white;
}
#hero p {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 12px auto 24px auto;
}

#hero button {
  padding: 12px 28px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 40%;
}
#hero button:focus {
  box-shadow: 1px;
}

/* button */
.btn {
  padding: 12px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}
.btn-brand {
  background-color: var(--brand);
  color: white;
}
.btn-brand:hover {
  color: white;
}

/* Navbar */
.navbar.bg-white {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover .navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  color: var(--brand);
}

/* Features */
.features {
  padding: 44px 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
.icon-box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: var(--brand);
  color: white;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  font-size: 34px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}
.features h5 {
  margin-top: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.features p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!-- NAV -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white sticky-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
      aria-controls="navbarNav"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#login">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- END OF NAV-->
<!-- HERO -->
<section id="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1 class="display-3">Brighter Brain</h1>
        <p>
          Creating a pathway to make access to education easier, flexible and
          profound.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p>
        <button class="btn btn-brand" type="button" id="button">
          Get started.
        </button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- END OF HERO-->

<!-- FEATURES -->
<section id="features">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 section-intro">
        <h1>Our Features</h1>
        <p>
          We have a very significant number of features which will help make
          educational life easily.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="features custom-card">
          <div class="icon-box">
            <i class="ri-live-fill"></i>
          </div>
          <h5>Features Title</h5>
          <p>
            Integrated administrative design and monitoring of teaching manuals,
            digital class and examinations deployable anywhere and anytime.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="custom-link">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- END OF FEATURES -->
```

Comment: I just ran the snippet here and it is working fine BUT it is not working when i run the code on Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Edge. I dont understand why it is acting like this.